# How to build _just_ libwebcore.so instead of the whole froyo source

Tags: android, webkit, android-2.2-froyo

Having checked out the froyo code I can successfully build froyo, but what I really want is only building libwebcore.so, is there a special target for this?

Just make -f Android.mk in external/webkit isn't working for the obvious reasons.

Comment: I know that libwebcore.so has a bunch of dependencies, so I'd be happy if there was something like a /system/lib only target by any chance, just avoiding building all of froyo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've sourced build/envsetup.sh and "lunched" appropriately...

Approach #1:

```
% mmm external/webkit
```

Approach #2

```
% cd external/webkit
% mm
```

Approach #3:

```
% make libwebcore
```

-or-

```
% make libwebcore libjs
```

depending on which javascript engine you have configured.

Answer (score 1):

make libwebcore seems to do the trick